# JQuery: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I am also using socket.io. There is an HTML table, and when a user clicks a button, my code is supposed to replace that table with a new one, however it gives the error message in the title.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<table>
                </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="1"></td>
                        <td class="2"></td>
                        <td class="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="4"></td>
                        <td class="5"></td>
                        <td class="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="7"></td>
                        <td class="8"></td>
                        <td class="9"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JQuery script:

```
socket.on('resetGranted', function() {
        $('table').replaceWith('<table>    //says error is here
                </tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="1"></td>
                        <td class="2"></td>
                        <td class="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="4"></td>
                        <td class="5"></td>
                        <td class="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="7"></td>
                        <td class="8"></td>
                        <td class="9"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>');
    })
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try using .html() instead of .replaceWith()

Comment: Don't think this is the cause of your error but note that what should be the opening `tbody` tag in your javascript is actually a closing tag, so you probably want to fix that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use backtick `` ` `` for multiline string

```js
console.log(`
    multi
    line
    string
    here
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('resetGranted', function() {
var htmlContent='<table>
            </tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="1"></td>
                    <td class="2"></td>
                    <td class="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="4"></td>
                    <td class="5"></td>
                    <td class="6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="7"></td>
                    <td class="8"></td>
                    <td class="9"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
        $('table').replaceWith(htmlContent);
    })
```